# How to move forward in VIM Tag Searching and Navigation?

Tags: vim, code-navigation

Ctrl + ] is to jump to the definition. Ctrl + T is to go back. What's the opposite of Ctrl + T?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
:help tag-stack


:[count]po[p][!]        Jump to [count] older entry in tag stack (default 1). 
                        See |tag-!| for [!].  {not in Vi}                     

:[count]ta[g][!]        Jump to [count] newer entry in tag stack (default 1). 
                        See |tag-!| for [!].  {not in Vi}
```

You can also use `ctrl + i` and `ctrl + o` to move forwards and backwards respectively through the jump list. This works with tag commands since they count as jump movements.

So: jump to a tag `ctrl + ]`

jump back: `ctr + o`

jump to tag again `ctrl + i`

`:help jump-motions`

Comment: It's worth noting that `CTRL + i` is the same as `tab` (for most terminals).

Comment: But ctrl + i does not seem to update the marker in the tag stack shown via `:tags`.

Answer (score 6):

The `:tag` command will move you down the tag stack.  It is not bound to a key combination, but you could map it yourself in your .vimrc file.